# Aplicação não roda com Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

Fiz duas pequenas aplicações no Visual Studio 2013, que fazem o seguinte:

- A primeira monta o serial e salva esse serial no registro do windows;
- A segunda lê a chave no registro do windows.

Quando rodo a aplicação *(como administrador)* pelo Visual Studio 2015 ela funciona sem problemas, mas quando vou na pasta **debug** e rodo o aplicativo direito, ela não funciona *(ela nem sequer aparece)*.

Em outra máquina funciona, mas na minha não funciona. Na máquina de um amigo funciona quando quer, ocorrendo o mesmo erro *(a aplicação não aparece)*.

Alguma ideia do que seja ?

Comment: Você deve publicar a aplicação, e não executar da pasta debug. Tente publicar sua aplicação e executar novamente.

Comment: Sendo que um se chama `Visual Studio 2013`  e outro `Visual Studio 2015` é porque devem ter diferenças, provavelmente algo que está tentando fazer dá no VS-15 pois este é mais avançado, mas não dá no VS-13 porque não deve ter a mesma maneira de debug que o de 2015..

Comment: E tem essa questão das versões também, e do .NET, do visual studio 2013 é 3.5 se nao me engano, e do 2015 é a 4.5, e as versões do .NET não tem retrocompatibilidade.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa dar release na sua aplicação.
Basta alterar no menu que é exibido na imagem abaixo onde está "Debug" mude para "Release" e rode novamente que o seu executável será criado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]